# Calling numeric JSON field-names

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using a simple REST API for a project and some of the data I need uses a numeric string as the top-level parent node. When attempting to call it in my javascript, it throws syntax errors.

here's the JSON object:

> {"23497400":{"id":23497400,"name":foobar,"profileIconId":627,"revisionDate":1431385425000}}

and here's where I'm throwing the error:

```
var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
var name1 = myArr.23497400.name;
```

There's definitely something terribly simple that I'm missing, right?

Comment: i think you have to do 
     var name1 = myArr["23497400"],name;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) if the key is not a valid identifier name.

```
var name1 = myArr['23497400'].name;
```

When you use the [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation),

> property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of
>   alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and
>   dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example,
>   object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

Answer (score 1):

Dot notation only works with property names that are valid identifiers: they must start with a letter, $, _ or unicode escape sequence. For all other property names (such as your numeric property in this case), you must use bracket notation, like so:

```
myArr['23497400'].name
```